# My timer won't update

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created an empty table in HTML; also, I added a button that allows the user to create as many empty rows as needed. But, for each new entry I added a minute counter and it starts at at zero for each new entry. My problem is that, while it shows the counter, it is not updating. If I add a new entry it stays at 0 and never updates. I tried looking into setIntervals and setTimeout functions but I can't get it to work properly. Can someone help me figure out what it is I am doing wrong? Many thanks in advance!

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>   
    <body>      
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <table id="myTable" class="editableTable">
            <caption><center>Hello World</center></caption>
            <thead> 
                <tr> 
                    <th>ID</th> 
                    <th>User</th> 
                    <th>Time</th> 
                    <th>Score</th> 
                </tr> 
            </thead> 
            <tbody id="tablebody"> 
                <tr style="display:none" id="templaterow"> 
                    <td></td> 
                    <td></td> 
                    <td id="timer"></td> 
                    <td></td>               
                </tr>           
            </tbody>            
        </table>
        <div class="tablebuttons"> <button onclick="myCreateFunction()">Add</button></div>      
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body{
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

button {
    text-align: center;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.buttons{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 600px;
}

* { 
    font-family:Consolas 
} 

.editableTable { 
    border:solid 1px; 
    width:100%; 
} 

.editableTable td { 
    border:solid 1px; 
} 

.editableTable .cellEditing { 
    padding: 0; 
} 
.editableTable .cellEditing input[type=text]{ 
    width:100%; 
    border:0; 
    background-color:rgb(255,253,210); 
}
```

**Javascript**

```
export function updateTime(seconds: number, minutes: number) {           
            $("#timer").last().html('{0}:{1}'.format(minutes, seconds));
            seconds += 1;
            if (seconds >= 60) {
                seconds = 0;
                minutes += 1;
            }
            if (minutes >= 60) {
                minutes = 0;
            }
            setTimeout(updateTime, 1000, seconds, minutes);
        };

        $(document).ready(function () {            
            setTimeout(updateTime, 1000, 0,0);
        });​

        export function myCreateFunction(): void {
            var newInstance = <HTMLTableElement>document.getElementById("templaterow").cloneNode(true);
            newInstance.style.display = "";
            newInstance.id = null;
            document.getElementById("tablebody").appendChild(newInstance);
        }
```

Comment: Could it be because you are using an `id` attribute multiple times? `id` attributes are intended to only be used once on a page, whereas `class` attributes are designed for multiple instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple things here....

First of all setTimeout will only trigger once, you should use setInterval

Second,  
You don't want to have multiple items with the same id, perhaps use class instead

Comment: Im fairly new at this. Could you please expand a little bit on the usage of class? An example, perhaps?

Comment: Hmmm... typically a the class attribute is to set a css class for formatting, however jquery will let you easily select all element with a particular class... such as $(".className")  
You were using # which is for ID, you should only have one element with a specific id, but you may have several elements with the same class, and select the appropriate one.

Comment: Perhaps this will help... https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/